# java: simple if condition in while loop does not work

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I'm currently working on a financial planning app for class but I cant get a loop with a condition inside it to work. It just keeps looping despite the condition - it's almost as if the condition is being ignored completely.

Here's my code - please help!

```
while (true){
        Scanner scanVar = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nEnter expenditure item: ");
        String myString = scanVar.nextLine();
        Scanner scanVar2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nEnter expenditure value: ");
        double myDouble = scanVar2.nextDouble();
        expenditureMap.put(myString, myDouble);
        Scanner scanVar3 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nAnother item? ");
        String myString2 = scanVar3.nextLine();
            if (myString2 == "yes") {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
    }
```

Many thanks,
Dylan

Comment: WRONG: "string1 == string2".  CORRECT: string1.equals(string2).  [Java String.equals versus ==](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Answer (score 1):

You really want to be using `mystring2.equals("yes")` (or even better, `"yes".equals(mystring2)` )

The `==` operator on objects tests for them being the identical instance, not the same string values....

```
String a = new String("yes");
String b = new String("yes");

a == b => false
a.equals(b) => true
```

Comment: Thanks...I've just realized after reading the previous answer" above - but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the == operater it is comparing if the object references match. You should use the equals operator

```
if (myString2.equals("yes"))
```

Answer (score 0):

change the condition as follows and then try:

```
if (myString2.equals("yes")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You shall use equals ... check this post

[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

reference comparison means checking if both objects have the same address in memoery 
value comparison means checking the value inside the objects